# Grafana visualization not displaying multiple lines

Tags: grafana, azure-application-insights, kql

The Grafana dashboard Im working on has a connection to an application insights resource.
I built a kql query like this:

```
app("apinsights").requests
| where timestamp >= $__timeFrom() and timestamp <= $__timeTo()
| extend XVAR = tostring(customDimensions["XPTO"]) 
| where XVAR != ""
| summarize RequestsPerXVAR = count() by XVAR, Time = bin(timestamp, $__interval)
| order by RequestsPerXVAR desc
```

If I remove the bin function of the summarize and look into a table visualization I can see that there are many different XVAR.

But I want a Time Series visualization.

The issue is that the returned visualization is not taking in account the many different XVAR. What can be done to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For starters you can use `$__timeFilter(timestamp)` to shorten your time filter clause.

Second - Grafana wants time series data ordered by time, so your last order by should be `order by Time asc`.
Also select "Format As: Time series" at the bottom of your query panel.